# How to setup Nginx and Mysql 5.7.16 on Windows?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I have to develop php project using Nginx and Mysql 5.7.16 on windows platform.
I can setup Nginx and Mysql 5.6 but my project leader want to use Mysql 5.7.16 because of customer requirements. in that Mysql 5.7.16 there is no my.ini file and i have replace it from version 5.6 and cannot start using below command.

```
net start mysql
```

It show as below error.

> The MySQL service is starting.
>     The MySQL service could not be started.
>      The service did not report an error.
>      More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.

Please guide me detail how to setup Nginx and Mysql 5.7.16 on Windows platform.

Comment: Remove the ini and see if it starts

Comment: Yes. it's start now. I just remove copied my.ini and rename the default included MYSQL 5.7.16 my-default.ini  to my.ini and type command bin\mysqld --initialize --console ... then It's started. THanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ini at time changes from version to version. So never copy the ini from old setup when installing new setup.

See the default ini of latest version and adjust that based on the variables that you want to change

Comment: Yes bro... Thanks for your suggestion.